# Adding methods to a SOAP webservice in production use

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP webservice running in production and being used by multiple different client implementations (written in .NET, PHP, Java, Ruby, Delphi...) and I need to add a method to the webservice.

My question is: is it possible that adding something to the current WSDL can break any of the client implementations? What I mean is there some SOAP-framework which goes berserk if the WSDL suddenly changes server side? I know that modifying an existing method (e.g. changing a parameter's type) will break stuff but what about adding a totally new method?

I'm guessing it should be OK but thought I'd ask if someone has run into problems when doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be OK, since the WSDL is normally used upon method stub generation, not during each call to a web service. Just make sure you don't change any parameter or return type